# WPF ScrollViewer not working in Grid programmatically populated

Tags: wpf, grid, label, scrollviewer, stackpanel

I have this situation in xaml

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5" Background="AliceBlue" Height="370">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid Name="DescriptionsGrid" MinHeight="0" MaxHeight="370" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"></Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

and I'm filling the Grid with the following

```
DescriptionsGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock { Text = description, TextWrapping = TextWrapping.WrapWithOverflow };
Label label = new Label { Content = textBlock, Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue) };
label.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(LoadXML);
DescriptionsGrid.Children.Add(label);
Grid.SetRow(DescriptionsGrid.Children[DescriptionsGrid.Children.Count - 1], description_counter);
description_counter++;
```

I can't define rows height as the description may be long enought to wrap the text to new line.

The scrollbar does not appears and new elements go hidden down below.

Any idea?

Comment: Do not use a StackPanel as parent of the ScrollViewer. It will not restrict the size of its child elements. Use another Grid or a DockPanel instead. As a general note, in order to populate a parent element with a dynamic set of child elements, consider using an ItemsControl.

Comment: Fixed both suggestions (thanks for that). Still the `ScrollViewer` doesn't scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion of @Clemens I rewrote the code, and found that the mistake was in the XML.

To populate the grid

```
        foreach (HostMessages hostMessage in hostMessagesList)
        {
            Label message = new Label
            {
                Content = new TextBlock {
                    Text = hostMessage.Description,
                    TextWrapping = TextWrapping.WrapWithOverflow
                },
                Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
                Cursor = Cursors.Hand
            };
            message.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(LoadXML);
            itemsControl.Items.Add(message);
        }
```

The XML is as follows

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" Background="AliceBlue" Height="370">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="370">
        <ItemsControl Name="itemsControl"></ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</DockPanel>
```

The mistake was assigning a `MaxHeight="370"` to the `Grid` and none to the `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: Seems you don't need the Grid at all. Declare the ItemsControl in XAML as a child of the ScrollViewer.

Comment: Correct. Fixed. Thanks.